# htaccess rewrite some urls but send all others to another page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^login      login_reg.php [L] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)       redirect.php?shortcode=$1 [L] [NC]
```

What I want is for anything other than '/login' and root '/' to be redirected to redirect.php with the request_url (the bit after the slash) being substituted as the shortcode GET variable.

However, the file above gives me an error: "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: You implemented an endless rewriting loop. Consider that the `L` flag only terminates the rewriting process _for that run_ . So either use the `END` flag instead or add another condition to prevent requests to `/redirect.php` to be redirected again.

Comment: @arkascha Makes sense now you've explained it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues:

1. Pattern of `login` will also match rewritten `login_reg.php`
2. `RewriteCond` will be applicable to immediate next `RewriteRule` only hence last rule is rewriting everything infinitely.
3. Flags need to be in a single `[...]`

You can use these rules in your .htaccess:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login_reg.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) redirect.php?shortcode=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I think I understand how this works now. Thank you.